# Why I can't update multiple rows?

Tags: php

i'm trying to update multiple rows using the MVC structure

I have one html table with the values from my database table.

I inserted at each row, one checkbox to check and submit.

When you submit, all the values from the checked rows appears inside textboxes to edit.

After edit, the user just need to click submit, and it will update the values.

But i'm having some problems doing that, because i'm using the MVC structure, and the Queries must be on model, and POSTs must be inside the controller, so, i'm having some problems adapting my code to the MVC rules.

VIEW:

```
function update_array($update_array){
foreach($update_array as $val){

    <table border='0' style='background: #1D7373; border-bottom: 1px solid #2e9c9c; color:white; width:100%;'>
    <tr>
  <input class='txtedit' type='hidden' name='update_job_id[".$val['job_id']."]'  value=".$val['job_id']."' />
      <td><input class='txtedit' type='text' name='u_description[".$val['job_id']."]' value='".$val['description']."' /></td>
      <td><input class='txtedit' type='text' name='u_job_name[".$val['job_id']."]' value='".$val['job_name']."' /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Model

```
    function printupdate($update_job_id, $checkbox, $editcheckbox, $u_job_name, $u_description, $checkedit, $savecheck){

    if(isset($_POST['save']) && !empty($_POST['savecheck'])) 
    { 

    $save_jo = "UPDATE job_offers SET job_name ='".$u_job_name."', description='$u_descritpion'
    WHERE job_id = '".$update_job_id."' ";

    $array = db_query($save_jo, '+');

    echo '<pre>';
echo $u_job_name;
echo $save_jo;
echo '</pre>';


}
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
     if(isset($_POST['save']) && !empty($_POST['savecheck'])){

            $countChecksave = count($_POST['savecheck']);
            $savecheck = $_POST['savecheck'];
            foreach ($savecheck as $id){

            $update_job_id = $_POST['update_job_id'][$id];
            $u_job_name =  $_POST['u_job_name'][$id];
            $u_description = $_POST['u_description'][$id];
            $checkedit = $_POST['checkedit'];

            printupdate($update_job_id, $checkbox, $editcheckbox, $u_job_name, $u_description, $checkedit, $savecheck);

            }

     }else{

 $update_job_id = NULL;
 $u_job_name = NULL;
 $u_description = NULL;
 $checkedit = NULL;
 $savecheck = NULL;
 }
```

Result:

```
UPDATE job_offers SET job_name ='1', description='1'
WHERE job_id = '108'

UPDATE job_offers SET job_name ='2', description='2'
WHERE job_id = '109' 

UPDATE job_offers SET job_name ='3', description='3'
WHERE job_id = '110' 

UPDATE job_offers SET job_name ='3', description='3'
WHERE job_id = '110'
```

Comment: What is the extra ' at the end of the queries? `UPDATE job_offers SET job_name ='3', description='3'
WHERE job_id = '110'' <-- This`

Comment: Please check how you send the job_id , it has an extra ' . Also, where is your savecheck code ? maybe that's where  the double job_id appears

Comment: I add this when i was copying the code, sorry